# Can I start a sentence with while?

Tags: essay

Can I say:

While for theorist A, this is perceived differently.

Ultimately, I'm asking if I can start my sentence with 'while' in this fashion.

Thanks!

Comment: This is more of a grammar question than about writing in general. A better place to ask questions like this would be https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you want "Whereas, for theorist A, … .".

Answer (score 1):

**No, because this is not a complete sentence.** Your example looks like it's from a scientific review or paper, where it would be too informal and thus inappropriate.

While you *can* start a sentence with 'while', you need to include the second half of the sentence, too. (Hint: Both halves of the sentence need to contain a verb.) In your case, that would probably be something along the lines of

> While theorist B claims X, theorist A perceives the problem differently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. Personally I'd go with 'whilst'. You are using the term as a conjunction so we probably need to see the preceding sentence.

Comment: The OPs entire sentence is a dependent clause. That is why not. It requires the other half, as Llewellyn has stated.